# Using one function with different variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Try to create two controllers with a same logic. when I use separate functions for each var it works. But when I try to pass var as parameter it does nothing.

Code here:

```js
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.Score1 = 0;
  $scope.Score2 = 0;

  $scope.add_btn = function(num) {
    $scope.num ++;
  };

  $scope.dist_btn = function(num) {
    if ($scope.num > 0) {
      $scope.num --;
    } else {
      $scope.num = 0;
    }
  };
}
```

```css
</style> <!-- Ugly Hack due to jsFiddle issue: http://goo.gl/BUfGZ --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<style>
```

```html
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <button ng-click="add_btn(Score1)">+</button>
        <input type="text" value="{{Score1}}">  
        <button ng-click="dist_btn(Score1)">-</button>
        <button ng-click="add_btn(Score2">+</button>
        <input type="text" value="{{Score2}}">  
        <button ng-click="dist_btn(Score2)">-</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try $scope[num] instead of $scope.num in your functions.  Before you progress further, I would suggest using a service to share logic between 2+ controllers instead of shared functions like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple and dirty solution :)

There could be something better

```js
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.Score = [0, 0];

  $scope.add_btn = function(num) {
    $scope.Score[num]++;
  };

  $scope.dist_btn = function(num) {    
    if ($scope.Score[num] > 0) {
      $scope.Score[num]--;
    } else {
      num = 0;
    }
  };
}
```

```css
</style> <!-- Ugly Hack due to jsFiddle issue: http://goo.gl/BUfGZ --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css">
<style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
          <button ng-click="add_btn(0)">+</button>
              <input type="text" value="{{Score[0]}}">  
          <button ng-click="dist_btn(0)">-</button>
          <button ng-click="add_btn(1)">+</button>
              <input type="text" value="{{Score[1]}}">  
          <button ng-click="dist_btn(1)">-</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this logic without useing any array, you used $scope.num but it creates a new variable on the scope so fails. this would work properly

```js
function Ctrl($scope) {
      $scope.Score1 = 0;
      $scope.Score2 = 0;

      $scope.add_btn = function(num,from) {
        num ++;
  if(from == 1)
   $scope.Score1 = num;
  else
   $scope.Score2 = num;
      };

      $scope.dist_btn = function(num,from ) {
   
        if (num > 0) {
          num --;
        } else {
          num = 0;
        }
  if(from == 1)
   $scope.Score1 = num;
  else
   $scope.Score2 = num;
      };
    }
```

```css
</style> <!-- Ugly Hack due to jsFiddle issue: http://goo.gl/BUfGZ --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<style>
```

```html
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <button ng-click="add_btn(Score1,1)">+</button>
        <input type="text" value="{{Score1}}">  
        <button ng-click="dist_btn(Score1,1)">-</button>
        <button ng-click="add_btn(Score2,2)">+</button>
        <input type="text" value="{{Score2}}">  
        <button ng-click="dist_btn(Score2,2)">-</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.num // find num inside #scope

$scope[num] // find the member inside scope variable with the value of num (Score1 in your case)
```

also send the parameter from the element like this:

```
 <button ng-click="add_btn('Score1')">+</button>
```

and instead num please refactor to id or something.. **in short**:

```
 $scope.add_btn = function(id) 
 { 
    $scope[id]++;
 };
```